# tailwind.config.js has no access to fonts specified in tailwind.css (nuxt.js 3, tailwindcss)

Tags: fonts, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, font-face, nuxtjs3

The tailwind.config.js file somehow has no access to fonts specified in the tailwind.css file. I am using nuxt.js 3 and tailwindcss, any help is greatly appreciated

## tailwind.css

```
/* /assets/css/tailwind.css */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  body {
    background-color: #16181c;
    color: #ecf9fb;
    font-family: "Inter", Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 1rem 5%;
  }
}

/* Inter Regular 400 */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Inter";
  src: url("../fonts/inter-regular-400.woff2");
}

/* Solway Bold 700 */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Solway";
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("../fonts/solway-bold-700.woff2");
}
```

The Solway Font gets applied correctly, so no Problems with importing it; Putting the `@font-face` inside `@layer base` doesn't do anything

## tailwind.config.js

```
/* tailwind.config.js */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "components/**/*.vue",
    "layouts/**/*.vue",
    "pages/**/*.vue",
    "composables/**/*.{js,ts}",
    "plugins/**/*.{js,ts}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        solway: ['"Solway" "Inter" Arial sans-serif'],
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        card: ["#26292f"],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

## How I tried to use the new font family

```
// /layouts/default.vue
<template>
  <header class="bg-card-0 rounded-2xl p-4 text-2xl">
    <NuxtLink to="/" class="font-solway font-bold">Second Hand</NuxtLink>
  </header>
  <slot />
</template>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the layer part here?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not sure but saw it [here](https://youtu.be/sOnBG2wUm1s?t=509). Removing the `@layer base` does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error was laying in the tailwind.config.js file.
What it was:

```js
fontFamily: {
  solway: ['"Solway" "Inter" Arial sans-serif'],
},
```

What is correct:

```js
fontFamily: {
  solway: ["Solway", "Inter", "Arial", "sans-serif"],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm importing my fonts the same way you do in the first snippet (outside the base layers). I think the `@layer base` is for styles you want to add to the default reset styles not font.

This [Log Rocket article](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-custom-fonts-tailwind-css/) imports the fonts the same way I mentioned.
[image]